# Displaying a website in a webview inside a mobile application - copyright infringment

Tags: copyright, website

Is it a breach of copyright to create a mobile application which simply displays another website in a webview as it is available online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

That would be in no way a bigger breach of copyright than creating yet another web browser.

Comment: What about if he displays just a part of the website? I have created another post regarding this issue and I would love to hear your views on it. 
https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58081/legal-issues-when-displaying-specific-content-of-a-website-inside-my-website-app